# New to Pi I need to connect a device via serial communication, how do I teach myself?

Tags: serial, c, communication

I've been asked to connect and control a finger-sensing device to a Raspberry PI. There is a protocol to respect called OSDP. It supposes a serial connection on top of RS485.

I'm a seasoned C/C++ programmer, but I have very little experience in connecting devices.

I was wondering, to make the task less daunting, maybe I should try a simple "fun project" which will make me feel comfortable with serial communication. Do you have any documentation or books to recommend?

Comment: Not really a suitable question for this site.  Personally I'd google for the model of sensor and raspberry pi.  It's quite likely it has been connected to the Pi already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi - Connect and power RS485 device](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90557/raspberry-pi-connect-and-power-rs485-device)

Comment: Many finger-sensing device have RS485 and RS232 (TTL UART). If so, then you can just use Rpi's serial/UART RxD, TxD pins to talk to your finger sensor. If you give me the link can check it out for you.

Comment: joan, that is not very helpful. Abolotnov, that is very helpful.

Comment: You need to find the pinouts. Then connect them and using python you can connect them. Or use an Arduino . There are a lot of tutorials for that. Copy any code and execute.